# Kill a process inside docker in a "R" state

Tags: process, docker, kill

I'm having a process on my server that I can't kill, even with `kill -9`.
It's in `R` state in `top` and in `ps`, and it's running inside docker.

It's a ls I've started in a very large folder.

It's taking 99% of a CPU and it's been running for more than 40 minutes now.

I've tried to kill docker (`docker kill`), but it hanged, now I can't get inside docker anymore:

```
root@server:~# docker exec -ti containername bash
oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:84: executing setns process caused \"exit status 15\""
```

How can I fix that without restarting the server ?

Comment: Considering that error is about `setns()`, you can try killing this process from the root `pid` namespace (i.e. without entering any of container's namespaces). If this won't help, probably we'll need more info for diagnostic (like `/proc/$PID/status` file of the process, some namespaces-related stuff like `ls -l /proc/$PID/ns`, etc.). You may also try manually `nsenter` container's namespaces and find the problematic namespace.

Comment: Also, can you share `docker info` output (with any sensitive info removed, of course)?